# Trouble converting money value to cents in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I story money values as integers like, price_in_cents or fee_in_cents. So, $1.00 would be stored in the database as 100.

Internally, I've always just typed 100 in the form when I meant 1.00, but I thought it would be simple to convert a form input of 1.00 to 100 in the model, but I'm having trouble.

No matter what I enter, I'm getting 0 for both values. Here's the model:

```
before_create :convert_money_to_cents
  attr_accessor :price, :fee

  private

  def convert_money_to_cents
    self.price_in_cents = price.to_i * 100
    self.fee_in_cents = fee.to_i * 100
  end
```

Any thoughts on why it's always coming up zero? I tried converting the string to various things (floats) and I'm still getting zeros.

Comment: What does your view and controller look like? I suspect that the price and fee are nil when they read the callback method.

Comment: I was using `text_field_tag` instead of `text_field` ... works now.

Comment: Does it work with "1.99", giving you 199? The `to_i` will actually give you 1, which, when multiplied by 100, gives the wrong answer of 100.

Comment: Oh, no ... it doesn't. I switched to `.to_d` and that was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def convert_money_to_cents
  self.price_in_cents = (self.price.to_d * 100).to_i
  self.fee_in_cents = (self.fee.to_d * 100).to_i
end
```

Comment: So, after trying that ... it looks like `price` and `fee` are actually `nil` ... but they're being submitted with the params. `"price"=>"1.99",
 "fee"=>".30",` ... so, I'm not sure why its nil when the method tries to use it.

Comment: You're probably missing the `self.` in the right side of the assignments, I've changed the code I posted accordingly. Try it.

Comment: Yeah, self was the first thing I tried when I saw the nil error. It's still coming up nil.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like:

```
class Numeric
  def to_cents
    (self.to_f * 100).to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: Or perhaps `self * 100.0`, which would do the type promotion more elegantly. Actually, `self * 100` may suffice: if `self` is an integer, integer arithmetic will give an accurate result, and if it's not, promotion will happen anyway.